# how to set gamma value in Python (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, svm, compiler-warnings

when I run this code I'm having a warning.

```
svm.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

!!! warning is as follow  !!!

> C:\Users#\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py:193: FutureWarning: >The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to >account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.
> "avoid this warning.", FutureWarning)

how to avoid this warning? or how can I set the value of gamma to scale?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `sklearn.svm.SVR(*your_current_args, gamma='scale')`

Check the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.svm) on various types of SVM in sklearn, you see the constructor for each having a gamma parameter for the constructor

Also, thats just a warning, not an error. Doesn't mean something bad is necessarily happening. Unless you have a specific reason to use one value of gamma or another you probably don't need to worry about it

They're just letting people know that the default value of `gamma` (if you don't specify it) will change in a future version of sklearn so that people don't get tripped up over the change when it happens